# What is the different between 'conv:' and 'local:'?

Tags: wpf, key, local, converters

Sometimes I see this format:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:NotConverter x:Key="notConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and sometimes the following:

```
<TextBlock.Resources>
    <conv:IsNullConverter x:Key="isNullConverter"/>
</TextBlock.Resources>
```

What is the different between "local:" and "conv:" in these two examples?

What other options can I use? (I remember that I saw also "style:")

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"Local" and "Conv" are just friendly names for namespaces referenced in your XAML.

You should have the definitions of these keywords at the beginning of your class, something like this:

```
<View x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Namespace.Converters"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         x:Name="MyClass"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
```

So you could use the keyword "conv" to access your converters being in the namespace "Namespace.Converters".

Of course, you could change the name "conv" to whatever name you are comfortable with.